# Change key in web.config to hold multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, nopcommerce

I wish to change the web.config so that the key will hold multiple values:

i have now amended the code as suggested,

what should happen is that if the product SKU starts with either O-GREET or O-PEGC then a punchout module will launch, if not the product is added to basket as normal,

in the web.config file i have:

```
<add key="PunchOutOnSKUPrefix" value="O-GREET,O-PEGC"/>
```

and in the relevant controller (ShoppingCartCOntroller)

```
Extensions.PunchOut punchOut = new Extensions.PunchOut();

            Boolean isPunchOut;
            String id = productVariant.Sku;
            String ticketId = null;

            // Check that the product supports Punch out integration by looking at the first 3 letters of its SKU

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            {
                isPunchOut = false;
            }
            else
            {
                option = id.Substring(0, 7);
                isPunchOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PunchOutOnSKUPrefix"].Split(',').DefaultOrNull(s => s.Equals(option));
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain what that line of code is trying to do?  `Split` returns an array, and you are comparing that with a string which is causing the error.

Comment: question now amended with new code and explanation

Comment: Now I understand more, changing to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PunchOutOnSKUPrefix"].Split(',').Any(s => id.StartsWith(s))` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split returns an array of options, if you want to search for specific value, use:

```
var option = id.Substring(0, 7);
var isPunchOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PunchOutOnSKUPrefix"].Split(',').DefaultOrNull(s => s.Equals(option));
```

If you want to check if `id` starts with anyone of the values, use:

```
var isPunchOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PunchOutOnSKUPrefix"].Split(',').Any(s => id.StartsWith(s));
```

Comment: Now amended question details with full code snippet and added amended code as per your suggestion, no errors just adds the product to basket as normal